# isSensor method of cocos2d-box2d not giving collision

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I am working on **box2d physics** game. In that i am facing one small problem that is for time interval I am making my physics body transparent to other physics body using group-index. That is working good. But, For some cases i want to know some of the b2body is colliding/overlapping with other bodies. For that, I tried to use **isSensor property** of b2fixture but i am not getting collision for transparent body.

My question is, **Is it necessary to make all bodies isSensor true??**

How can i solved this problem?

MyContactListner.mm

```
#import "MyContactListener.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
MyContactListener::MyContactListener() : _contacts() {
}

MyContactListener::~MyContactListener() {
}

void MyContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {
    MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
    _contacts.push_back(myContact);
}

void MyContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact) {
    MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
    std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    pos = std::find(_contacts.begin(), _contacts.end(), myContact);
    if (pos != _contacts.end()) {
        _contacts.erase(pos);
    }
}

void MyContactListener::PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, 
                                 const b2Manifold* oldManifold) {
}

void MyContactListener::PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, 
                                  const b2ContactImpulse* impulse) {
}
```

Comment: for sensor body you have to check collision in the beigncontact/end contact

Comment: yes... i am checking that but i am not geting contacts.

Comment: can you show ur beign contact code

Comment: you set user data to your fixture/body then check that you are geting user data or not

Comment: i put log in begin contact but when bodies are overlapping, i am not getting that log printed. Is it necessary that both bodies must be isSensor enabled?

Comment: no it is not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the groupIndex and filter bits is to make fixtures ignore each other completely, so what you're describing sounds correct. If you want two fixtures to give you BeginContact/EndContact callbacks, you'll have to set the groupIndex and filter bits to allow it. You can see how the default check is done here: http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2WorldCallbacks.cpp

You can make your own subclass of b2ContactFilter to customize this behavior (use b2World::SetContactListener to tell the world to use your custom class).

Comment: Done...Just made some code in b2WorldCallbacks.cpp and its done.